# Filter View, Text Starts With in Custom Formula

Tags: google-sheets

In Google docs (spreadsheet) under Filter View, I am trying to write a custom formula for multiple conditions.  For example, in column O, I may have "Jury Room" and also "Jury Rooms" and so I am trying to filter for anything beginning with just "Jury."  Under the predefined conditions there is "Text Starts With" which would serve my purpose but I also want to search for other items in the same filter condition.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with a regexmatch function using the `custom formula` option under the filter by condition options instead of `starts with`:

```
=regexmatch(A:A,"^Jury|^Something")
```

Explanation:

in regexes: the `^` means beginning of string/line and the `|` is the `OR` operator for regexes

Comment: Thank you Aurielle,  this worked and you have introduced me to use of regular expressions, and so I have done already all sorts of things beyond my initial question.  I appreciate this web site and I appreciate you for taking the the time to respond to my request for assistance.    Tim